# How to clamp head when looking at object in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity NavMeshAgent that walks around the player. The agent has a "head" that looks at the player independent of the body. This works except when it walks past the player the head rotates way too much - it isn't clamped. I need to clamp the rotation so that it only turns as much as a human neck.

I tried clamping it myself which works fine when the agent is looking straight ahead but when the agent rotates, my clamping is off:

```cs
    void LateUpdate()
    {
            Vector3 playerHead = GetPlayerHead();

            head.LookAt(playerHead);

            float clampedAngleY = head.eulerAngles.y;

            if (clampedAngleY >= 180 && clampedAngleY <= 315)
            {
                clampedAngleY = 315;
            }
            else if (clampedAngleY >= 45 && clampedAngleY <= 315)
            {
                clampedAngleY = 45;
            }

            head.eulerAngles = new Vector3(head.eulerAngles.x, clampedAngleY, head.eulerAngles.z);
    }
```

How do I factor in the agent's rotation?

I've tried subtracting the agent's rotation, performing my clamping then re-applying the rotation but that just behaves odd:

```
    void LateUpdate()
    {
            Vector3 playerHead = GetPlayerHead();

            head.LookAt(playerHead);

            float clampedAngleY = head.eulerAngles.y - transform.eulerAngles.y;

            if (clampedAngleY >= 180 && clampedAngleY <= 315)
            {
                clampedAngleY = 315;
            }
            else if (clampedAngleY >= 45 && clampedAngleY <= 315)
            {
                clampedAngleY = 45;
            }

            clampedAngleY = transform.eulerAngles.y + clampedAngleY;

            head.eulerAngles = new Vector3(head.eulerAngles.x, clampedAngleY, head.eulerAngles.z);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use „Mathf.clamp” method? It seems like something that you are looking to. [[Docs]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html)

Example usage:

```
SomeValue = Mathf.Clamp(value, min, max);
```

Comment: You can use it to every angle and then apply them to quaterion.

Comment: Yes I've tried it and nothing changes. I can clamp the rotation fine but it never factors in the parent's rotation